What is the state of pasted text?
Pasted text has a different background colour.
That colour disappears on any keypress.
To me, this seems like some state is being left.
Can someone explain?

Please provide an example starting from emacs -Q including the buffer you cut/copied from, the buffer you pasted to, including their major modes, any properties the cut text had, any properties the pasted text has, and how exactly you cut/copied and pasted (e.g. using the kill ring, using the clipboard, using some other mechanism - e.g. X cut-buffers) and any other relevant considerations. Needless to say, I cannot reproduce using the kill ring.

This may be a feature introduced by other module - it is called highlight pasted text, comes from vim and has an Emacs implementation in this package. Do you use such package? There are also other packages doing that.

@Ian That's the answer. Thank you

@NickD I think you answered unintentionally :) with your  comment about C-x C-x region here

I thought the answer was that you were using a third-party package to highlight the paste. In any case, I think you need to add a lot more detail to the question before it becomes answerable.
